# Use Linq to Access Nested Data from IEnumerable<Claim>

Tags: c#, .net, linq, claims

I am having some trouble accessing deeply nested values from an `IEnumerable<Claim>` object in my .NET application.

I read through a dozen or so similar questions on here but they all were using a Json object of some kind and, as far as I can tell, `IEnumerable<Claim>` cannot be accessed like one and cannot be easily parsed into one.

Here is an example of what the values in the ClaimsPrinciple look like in the Debugger:

```
{exp: 1234567}
{iat: 7654321}
{_claims_names: {"groups":"src1"}}
{_claims_sources: {"src1":{"endpoint":"http://graph.windows.net..."}}}
{ipaddr: 1.1.2.2}
{http://schemas.microsoft.com/claims/authnmethodsreferences: rsa}
{http://schemas.microsoft.com/claims/authnmethodsreferences: mfa}
```

Based on my research, Claims are generally supposed to be straightforward Key/Value pairs, and nesting data is not recommended. But I didn't create a custom claim type; this is just what I'm getting back from my Authentication service.

I can easily access claims or sets of claims from the list if they're just regular key/pair values. For example if I need all the active authentication methods on an account I can do this and it works perfectly:

```
var authMethodsRes = claims.Where(c => c.Type == "http://schemas.microsoft.com/claims/authnmethodsreferences");
var authMethodsCodes = authMethodsRes.Select(c => c.Value).ToList();
```

But I also need to access the values that are nested inside other values like the `"http://graph.windows.net..."` URL in the example above. How to I get to it? Would I have to dig in one level at a time using `.Select` and casting back to an `IEnumerable<Claim>`

I tried doing this:

```
var claimExtract = claims.Where(c => c.Type == "_claims_sources");
claimExtract = (IEnumerable<Claim>)claimExtract.Select(c => c.Value);
claimExtract = (IEnumerable<Claim>)claimExtract.Select(c => c.Value);
valueExtract = claimExtract.Select(c => c.Value).ToString();
```

But `claims.Where(c => c.Type == "_claims_sources");` [returns an empty Results list](https://i.imgur.com/onW2XCd.png) so I am truly baffled as to how to proceed.

Comment: Maybe there's a different schema for the inner one instead of `http://schemas.microsoft.com/claims/authnmethodsreferences` ?

Comment: I'm having a hard time figuring out what this question is asking. You have a *sequence of claims*, so let's clarify first: are you trying to do some operation on *each claim* -- like "I have a sequence of claims and I want a sequence of names" -- or are you trying to do some operation on *the sequence as a whole*, like "I have a sequence of claims and I want to know how many there are in the sequence"? Or are you trying to do an operation on a *specific* claim that may or may not be in the sequence?

Comment: @EricLippert I am trying to access a value that's nested inside a claim with multiple inner key/pair values. Like the "http://graph.windows.net..." value on line 4 of my example. OP Edited for (hopefully) clarity.

Comment: Try starting with a SelectMany, flattening each nested sequence and then filtering the results.

Comment: Do you know beforehand how deeply nested the one you are looking for will be?

Comment: @jasonmchoe in this case yes. For now it does not need to be generalized. I almost wish i could cast the whole claims object as a raw string and just use RegEx to pull the URL out.

Comment: @Rickey I tried doing this but cannot figure out a parameter that SelectMany will accept. I tired `SelectMany(c => c)` which I have used in the past to turn 2-D arrays of ints into a single List<int> with all the values but I"m getting a "type cannot be inferred from usage" error here. 

I guess Claims doesn't implement `IEnumerable<TResult>` ?